# Adding Attachment to Trello card via ruby-trello gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rubygems, trello

I am using the ruby-trello gem, and I am having some difficulty adding an Attachment to a card.

Card created without problems.
Checklists added, all good.

When I try to create an attachment with
`Trello::Attachment::create(url: 'Some URL here')`
I get an error: TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String). 
Am I missing some required values in the creation or have I got the whole thing wrong?

Comment: Does the error come with a backtrace (maybe in the log files)? If so please post the full error here. Also, you are really sure that the URL you provided is really a URL, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`add_attachment`](https://github.com/jeremytregunna/ruby-trello/blob/master/lib/trello/card.rb#L420) method in the Card class, with the first parameter being either a file or a URL (like in your case), and the second parameter being an optional name for the attachment.

Here's a working example:

```
require "trello"

public_key = "x"
member_token = "x"
board_id = "x"

Trello.configure do |config|
  config.developer_public_key = public_key
  config.member_token = member_token
end

board = Trello::Board.find(board_id)
list = board.lists.first
card = list.cards.first

attachment = card.add_attachment("https://google.com", "Link to Google")
```